# SonarQube error, after upgrading to 5.6.6

Tags: sonarqube, maven-3

I recently upgraded my local SonarQube instance from `5.6.4` to `5.6.6`, now a recently working java class keeps failing with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project cw2-core-build: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'C:\Users\rob\workspace\server\core-build\deltasync-impl\src\main\java\org\zcore\sync\deltasync\builder\DeltaSyncOperationBuilder.java': String index out of range: 0 -> [Help 1]
```

Trying to exclude the class via `<sonar.exclusions>**/DeltaSyncOperationBuilder</sonar.exclusions>` in my `pom.xml` didn't have an impact on running my sonar step.

How can I fix my uploads to have it back in a working state?

PS: I'm using Maven `v3.5.0`, running sonar-maven-plugin `v3.3.0.603`.

Comment: What you mean by upload, do you want to filter file from SVN commit ?

Comment: No, by upload i mean running the sonar step on mvn, currently using `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar`

Comment: What version of the SonarJava analyzer are you using? You can find this in Administration > System > Update Center

Comment: Currently using `v4.14.0.11784`.

Comment: @SACn Thanks, added some clarification.

Comment: @Rob I guess this could be a type ```<sonar.exclusions>**/DeltaSyncOperationBuilder</sonar.exclusions>``` should contain file externsion - isn't it. So it should be ```<sonar.exclusions>**/DeltaSyncOperationBuilder.java</sonar.exclusions>```.

Comment: @SACn Thanks, quite useful workaround so far.